# Where did my Low Quality Post reviews go?

Tags: support, review-queues

Over the past twenty or so hours, I have reviewed about 15 [Low Quality Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/) from the queue (about 10 yesterday, 5 today). However, only [one of them shows up in my review history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/266143/codecaster?tab=activity&sort=reviews).

So are LQP reviews removed from your history, when, and why? From [Overmeta: Highlight deleted posts in Low Quality Posts history, similar to deleted flagged posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179741/highlight-deleted-posts-in-low-quality-posts-history-similar-to-deleted-flagged) I assume that they should remain visible in your history, even when the post in question got deleted.

Comment: I found your reviews [here](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/history?page=16)(page will change as more reviews happen) It shows you did 5 reviews and only one of them is not deleted so that jives with your suspicion that it is only showing your non-deleted history.

Comment: @NathanOliver: It's "jibes".

Comment: Thanks for the review work, by the way. It's frustrating when my flags age away!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They do remain visible in the history, but it is [this review history](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/history) they're talking about in the Overmeta post you mentioned.

If you're a <10k-user, you only see your own reviews; if not, you'll also see other users' reviews, so your own reviews may be hidden in the next pages. But as @rene points out, there is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/history?userId=1) in the lower right corner which filters out your own reviews.

Comment: you can filter on your own reviews at the bottom of the history page

Comment: Well, that clears it up, thanks. A bit unintuitive that your own reviews don't show up on your own review page, but alright. I also seem to have grossly overestimated the total number of reviews done.

Comment: Additionally, apparently the posts I voted to delete on are displayed on my Votes tab. Case closed. :) Don't know whether it's worthy a feature request to keep those reviews on the review tab.